Why wouldn't People become a mage?
My world is about 19th century and has magic, but I need a reason that normal people would still exist.
My magic system is heavily based in physics with four key areas of magic: Velocity, Mass, Direction, and Shape, with heat as a sub-type of velocity. Magic is channeled through runes that must be transcribed beforehand into the object that a mage wants to manipulate.
Once the rune is complete a mage uses their own energy (not mana) to activate the rune. A Velocity Rune for example when channeled, infuses an object with an intense amount of kinetic energy until that object is given direction or, in most cases, pushed.
A Mages energy is really just the energy that everyone gets from eating, so if a mage uses magic they will be hungry afterwards. To give a reference, an active mage can starve in under a day.
Depending on the orientation of the rune, its effects will differ. For Direction Magic this is important as a direction rune locks an object into a certain trajectory, this can manifest in an arrow weaving through a forest or a zipline with no line.
Mass is simple and powerful but requires the most energy to use, simply allowing a mage to control the weight of an object like making a small stone weigh several Tonnes or a giant boulder light enough carry.
Shape is the strangest of the magic types. When infused a Runed hammer can mold anything as easily as clay, softening any surface it strikes, allowing for a chisel that can cut through anything.
What can I change so that not everyone becomes a mage?

Questions about the motivations of individuals or groups of individuals are not a good fit for this site. There is far too much room for worldbuilder discretion for the question to be anything other than an open ended request for brainstorming. We are not here to generate ideas for you.

@sphennings He's not asking for how individuals or governments make a specific choice, but rather how to build a societal norm that is consistent with the rules of his setting.  These questions are allowed.

We have such Mages in the real world. They are called Engineers, and they draw Runes called Schematics and Technical Drawings which then skilled Artisans interpret in order to make Wondrous Things. Nevertheless, becoming an Engineer is a long and arduous Labor and the Rewards are meagre, so that few People have the Desire and Strength follow this Noble Calling. Long story short, how come that not everyone becomes a medical doctor or an engineer or a firefighter or a marine or you get the idea. In the immortal words of Kurt Vonnegut, it takes all kinds of people to make a world.

So they’re asking for brainstorming and idea generation which are not permitted. This is a question with many equally valid answers which makes it fundamentally incompatible with the stack exchange model. Literally any possible reason for a religious prohibition is a valid answer.

you've explained everythign but what it takes to become a mage, which means it is unasnwerable. do they need extensive training, the right bloodline, precision mathmatics you make the rules.

This question is similar to: If magic is accessed through tattoos, how do I prevent everyone from having magic?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@gs "Magic is channeled through runes that must be transcribed beforehand into the object that a mage wants to manipulate." So his definition of a mage is the person making the runes, not necessarily someone who just has access to a runed object (like tattooed skin.)

@Nosajimiki I'll withdraw vtc, I think it might still be a duplicate on deeper principles, though.

@sphennings What makes you think this is a brainstorming question?  He has not asked for a list of ideas, and most of the answers so far are very close variations of one another.

Brainstorming isn't about asking for each answer to be a list. Brainstorming is about asking an open ended question where there are many equally valid answers. In aggregate they are getting us to generate a list of ideas for them. Remember that we prohibit idea generation because it violates both the too broad and POB VTC reasons. We used to have it as a custom close reason. We removed it because we thought having broad and POB rendered it redundant. We explicitly did not make idea generation permissible when we did this. It is still fundamentally not OK in the SO model.

Pick any opinion you have that is in your mind proven to be better. Do it on a topic that is colloquially considered to be divisive. There is a significant amount of people not doing what you believe to be objectively better. Why is that? Why do people smoke after the harmful effects have been shown? Why do some people refuse to walk under ladders even though there is no empirical evidence to support it negatively impacting what happens to you? Relevant to your starvation point: why do people eat more than their doctor recommends their daily intake is? Why do they not exercise?

@sphennings He has defined both the key features of his magic system and the key features of the society he wants to form around it.  He just needs help resolving the relationship between his rune magic system and a society with a limited number of mages making this a textbook internal consistency problem.  Asking for help solving a specific relationship problem between two features of the setting is not Idea Generation; so, I don't really see your point.

Because literally any reason a human could choose to not become proficient in magic is an equally valid answer to this question. You yourself throw 3 whole categories of ideas that OP could choose to use. OP's question does not require a behavioral solution, as written it could also be answered by a structural impediment. You can see answers below that fill in details about the magic system, without contradicting any of OP's already established facts. Regardless of whether it's idea generation or not, this question has too many valid answers to be suitable for this site.

Short of some hard barrier to entry (such as a dangerous ritual necessary to harness one's energy), many — if not most — people will use some level of magic in their daily lives. However, few people will invest in more than a few everyday utility runes due to a few soft barriers.
Knowledge
Mages have to know how to draw all those complex runes in order to do anything. Therefore, becoming a mage involves quite a bit of study. As was the case with full literacy during the Middle Ages, this isn't worth it to most people; people may learn what's necessary for their job, but most won't bother going beyond it.
Power Drain
In your system, magic runs off the user's "energy" (however you mean that). In the same way that naturally non-athletic people don't become football players, people with little energy (or, just as importantly, the stamina needed to use it) generally won't bother investing in something where the deck is stacked against them.
The Invisible Hand
Why learn all that fancy magic when you can just pay someone else to do it for you? As long as the aforementioned someone is charging less than the opportunity cost of learning how to do it yourself, you almost certainly won't. A builder does not need to know how to forge a hammer; he just needs to know who to get it from and how to use it.
Cumbersomeness
Runes are not like a magic wand that you can wave around to make things happen. They must be applied directly to what they affect. Thus, while they're great for enchanting, warding, and so on, runes are unsuited for casting on the fly.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you really want a hard barrier to entry,
Corruption
On a certain level, magic is intent made reality. This allows users to make great (and sometimes terrible) works, but it also affects them to an extent. Crafting and powering a Rune of Deathly Crushing requires a certain degree of malice and brutal hostility towards life in the moment of crafting. Even if only for a moment, you must truly desire that anything affected by the ward or enchanted item die, crushed into a paste. Magic shapes the enchantment with your intent, but it also shapes you. Cast it enough times, and you shall become cruel, hateful, and sadistic, wishing nothing more than to destroy others.
While I used an extremely negative intent as an example, note that this molding is not necessarily negative. If, for example, you often cast spells to help others, you will become more helpful (in whatever aspect(s) of that the spells you use embody.) The point is, magic changes you. Do it too much, and you will cease to exist, supplanted by the intents you express. Some people see this as a worthwhile trade; in their minds, there is only power, and those too weak to seize it. They become mages. The vast majority do not see things this way, so they avoid casting magic.

Your setting is already internally consistant
Asking why everyone is not a mage in your setting is like asking why everyone is not a doctor or programmer today.  The stuff doctors and programmers can do is like magic, but it is is not easy to learn, and there are so many disciplines that it is impossible to master every kind of medicine or coding stack meaning that when most people need medical or programming assistance, they just hire someone to do it instead of dedicating years to learning to do it themselves.
Also, the existence of these professions do not negate that fact that we still need a lot of people to do more mundane jobs: cooks, garbage men, tailors, etc.  These guys may use magically imbued objects made by mages, but do not need to learn runecraft to do their jobs; so, no one is going to invest the time and effort into teaching you too.
Features of your setting (and basic human nature) that will already directly limit mage numbers

You need to be crafty enough to make the ruins.  Learning to write is something every child does, but learning to create the runes in enough exact detail that they work could take years of focused study, and only a handful of people may actually have the eye hand coordination to do it. I once had a DM who described rune smithing as trying to forge the written words of divine beings to trick nature into bending to your will.  It's not enough to write the runes, but it has to be a precise counterfeit. Historically, counterfeiters have existed, but less than 1 in 100 people are good enough to forge government documents or train tickets, much less the handwriting of divine beings; so, it is not a thing everyone even can have the skills to master.
Burnout is hard to resist when your job just involves doing something that takes a lot of stress or skill, but any job that literally sucks the energy from your body is going to be really hard to stay motivated to do for a long time.  You may see that plenty of people study magic when they are young, but feel so drained trying to do it all the time that they abandon it before they actually get any good at it.  It takes a special sort of psyche to deal with the constant physical and emotional consequences of casting on a regular basis, but if you don't practice it, you can not do it, or at least not well enough to do anything useful.
Licensing or other entry barriers tend to emerge in any field where those who do it do not want too many new people learning to do it to so that they can continue to charge top dollar.  A few modern examples of this are the Medical Associations and the Bar Associations which limit the number of people who can become doctors and lawyers respectively to make sure that the demand stays high and the supply low so that they can price gouge their services.  In the Medieval/Renaissance periods, this is basically what the trade guilds were; so, your mage guilds could lobby or even directly enforce laws and regulations that prevent unlicensed mages from practicing magic so that they can decide who is or is not allowed to use it, even if everyone could in theory learn to do it themselves.


Supply and demand and the notion of specialization already takes care of this. When you need electrical work done, you hire an electrician, you don't spend months or years learning electrical code. If you need some magic, most people will hire a mage rather than become one.
If there are no mages at all, being a mage is probably quite valuable since you can do things no one else can. If there are many, many mages, hiring a mage to do something for you is probably quite cheap, since there are so many mages they need to compete with each other on price. At some point, becoming a mage is simply not worthwhile, since you have affordable access to magic whether you are a mage or not. There is no reason everyone should become a mage any more than everyone should choose to learn any other specialized skill which they can hire out much easier.
Society will naturally find an equilibrium that balances the number of mages, the feats they can perform, and the investment required to become one. If being a mage becomes is very useful and not very costly, you get more mages, but if being a mage takes intense effort for little benefit, you get fewer mages.

Why does everyone today not become a financier?
Or a politician, or a doctor, or a lawyer, or anything else that Hollywood promotes as being powerful and wealthy? We all want that, right?

Some people simply don't have the talent.
Some people have other addictions/distractions/interests.
Some people don't have the resources to take that educational avenue.
Some people were born into the "wrong family" or to the "wrong side of the tracks."

And all that assumes...

The mages haven't unionized, limiting membership.
The employers of mages don't expect graduation with honors from the "right schools."
The government hasn't licensed the mages, bringing to bear the force of law against magic performed by unlicensed mages.

All of which makes it a royal pain in the patootie to be a mage. It's worth noting that what I've described isn't too terribly far off what medical practitioners face. In other words, there's nothing special about your mages. It's just another occupation, just like every occupation on Earth — which means you can apply any of the reasons used here on Earth to rationalize not taking a career in something wealthy and powerful.
And that applies to most of us.

Horror.
The magic starts with energy in the mage's body.  And it has the power to reshape, to propel violently, to increase weight to absurd proportions, to create immense heat.  And perhaps the only thing limiting that power from wreaking havoc on the user himself, is whether some moderately complicated runes can be discerned by the threads of the magic within the creases of his hands or the branching of his arterioles.
The first time a mage succeeds in working magic, there is a significant chance of death or major deformity due to some hidden rune-like configuration within his own body.  Then there is the risk that mishandling the spell sends an object shooting back toward him, or explodes it.  Then there is the slow wearing down of his mitochondria as they struggle to accommodate the extraordinary energy requirements, causing cells of brain and body to undergo programmed cell death.  The risk of apoplexy, aneurysm and stroke due to the circulatory load.  The inexplicable chips of unknown materials he occasionally finds buried in his flesh, summoned in from god knows where.  The groaning of p-branes shuddering under violations of conservation of mass, and the disturbing thoughts of the alien creatures that patrol those extradimensional reefs.
No... magic is not for most people.  It is dreaded, avoided -- Even the basic theoretical explanations of magic are rationed strictly to a limited cadre with the potential to cast magic successfully and the economic and social disposability to try.

The same reason not everyone becomes a Billionaire CEO
Becoming a Mage requires a number of things

Extreme intelligence
Risk Taking
Luck
Access to a Mentor
Ability to single-focus on a big-picture issue
Massive amounts of Work Ethic etc.

Lets go through them
Intelligence - I think this one is fairly self-evident, but Magic is complicated and complicated things require intelligence to use. The more the Intelligence, the easier it is to understand, manipulate and then re-apply ideas.
Risk Taking - A Spell might not work out how you want. Suddenly you have turned all the first born of the city into monsters that murder their families. In order to learn, a Mage has to be willing to fail - and some may not be willing to take the risk
Luck - Plenty of people have had brilliant ideas that were ahead of their time, not quite right etc. And some people have come along with just the right idea at the right time. Think of the Pet Rock - such a silly a simple idea, yet it made the guy who came up with it a chunk of change.
Access to a Mentor - Almost all big Business types have had people that they have worked with and helped guide them. In many instances, people who are successful, when they see someone with the right attributes, they are very willing to help them out. For a Mage, a high ranking mage might notice something about someone and decide they are worthy of further teaching
Ability to Focus - This is sort of an amalgamation of other points - but in order to be a Mage, you have to fully commit to it. Like being a professional Musician, there comes a point where you have to quit your day job and fully focus your entire existence on becoming a Professional Musician. Not everyone can make that decision and remain focused on the goal. Often they are focused on the results of the goal (Fame, Wealth, Women etc.) rather than the Goal itself.
Work Ethic - although I have not worked with Billionaires (there are few in NZ) - I have had the pleasure of working with a number of Multi-Millionaire business owners. One of them had a 'hobby' of setting up new companies, making them profitable and then selling them. He didn't like the tedium of running a company long-term, but he loved the challenge of creating something from nothing. All of the people who are wealthy I have dealt with had a work ethic that made me feel lazy. They were always working. Always had at least 2-3 money making ventures going at any one time. Your Mage needs that same level of effort to get good enough to be competent. No goofing off with the Tavern Wenches or galavanting about at Tournaments - your mage has to eschew just about everything to get to the point where they are starting to be useful.

The wealthy people thing might be presection bias though. Youre much more likely to run into a multimillionare that works, does things, speaks with people than the ones that sit on their yacht and drink cocktails all day.

Increase the challenge
You can put simple intellectual challenges into it. For instance, with everything running on some computational platform these days, why isn't everyone becoming a programmer?
This has several reasons, and all of them could be applied to magecraft.

Not everyone is capable of thinking in the level of detail required to write software.
They perceive programming to be on the level of manual labor, and don't want to lower themselves from the big picture.
They misunderstand the aptitudes required, and they think that it requires too much math.
It really does require more math than some people are capable of.

You can include a level of fine control that takes a lot of practice. That would result in most people being able to perform basic cantrips, but if they try to do anything meaningful, they get unfortunate results.
You can make manipulation of magic act like a muscle. For instance, most people don't realize that singing is a muscle control activity, and as such don't know that expanding your range is like lifting weights.
Really, you could do all of these thing simultaneously, and add in the ability to work with others as a further obstacle.

Bureaucracy
Magic is heavily regulated. It's illegal to practice without a license. And the license is not easy to obtain. It requires regular examinations for proof of control, annual fees, and lots of paperwork.
